# How to install Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, software-center

I do not like the new GNOME software center. I cannot find some old programs I had on Ubuntu 14.04. (Like OpenJDK Java 8 Runtime) Is there a way that I can install the old Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-center`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing the package software-center with `sudo apt install software-center` :)

Comment: I tried doing that on another pc and got this: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`